# How do I take The Lat and Lon of this fetch data and store it in a variable too be used somewhere else?

Tags: javascript

So I have a fetch request that gives me Lat and Lon of a city when you do "convertToCords.GetCords("london")" In the console. But how would I save that Lat and Lon into seperate variables to be used in another fetch??

Here is my JS

```
var convertToCords = {
    Key: "c9676e6950f05e39b2aae36c413d9dff",

    GetCords: function (cityname) {
        fetch(
            "https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + cityname + "&limit=1&appid=c9676e6950f05e39b2aae36c413d9dff"
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => console.log(data));
    },
    showresults: function(data){
        
    }
}
```

Here is what the console gives me

```
{name: 'London', local_names: {…}, lat: 51.5073219, lon: -0.1276474,
```

Comment: You can't directly return the lat/lon values from GetCords.  You would either need to use async/await or run the following fetch from within the final then of the GetCords fetch.

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you?

```
var convertToCords = {
  key: "---",

  GetCords: async function(cityname) {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + cityname + "&limit=1&appid=c9676e6950f05e39b2aae36c413d9dff"
    );

    return await response.json();
  },
  ShowResults: async function() {
    let [{lat, lon}] = await convertToCords.GetCords("paris")

    // do something with lat and lon
    
    console.log(lat, lon)
  }
}

convertToCords.ShowResults()
```

**By the way never publicly show your api keys**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).